# En Neodatis me crea 7 objetos cuando solo deberían ser 3

Tags: base-de-datos, neodatis

Estoy intentando hacer una mini base de datos de consolas y videojuegos. La idea es que cada juego tiene asociada una consola. Por algún motivo después de crear las 3 consolas me crea otra más por cada juego que inserto haciendo un total de 7 consolas, clonando los datos de las ya creadas. No tengo ni idea de lo que puede ser y empiezo a pensar que puede ser algún fallo puntual de neodatis. La pregunta del millón es: ¿qué está pasando?

CLASE MAIN:

```
public class main {

    static neodatis neo = new neodatis();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        inserta_todo();
        neo.getConsolas();
        neo.getJuegos();

    }

    public static void inserta_todo(){
        consola ps3 = new consola("PS3", 1, 3, 160, 0);
        consola ps4 = new consola("PS4",2,0,500,1000);
        consola xbox360 = new consola("XBOX 360", 2, 0, 120, 0);

        juego doom = new juego("DOOM", "Bluray", 1, ps4);
        juego battleborn = new juego("Battleborn", "Bluray", 1, ps4);
        juego sonic_generations = new juego("Sonic Generations", "Dvd", 1, xbox360);
        juego resident_evil_6 = new juego("Resident Evil 6", "Bluray", 1, ps3);

        neo.nueva_consola(ps3);
        neo.nueva_consola(ps4);
        neo.nueva_consola(xbox360);

        neo.nuevo_juego(doom);
        neo.nuevo_juego(battleborn);
        neo.nuevo_juego(sonic_generations);
        neo.nuevo_juego(resident_evil_6);        
    }
}
```

CLASE JUEGO:

```
package u6_repaso_junio;

public class juego {
    private String titulo, formato;
    private int cant_almacenamiento;
    private consola consola;

    public juego(String titulo, String formato, int cant_almacenamiento, consola consola) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.formato = formato;
        this.cant_almacenamiento = cant_almacenamiento;
        this.consola = consola;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getFormato() {
        return formato;
    }

    public void setFormato(String formato) {
        this.formato = formato;
    }

    public int getCant_almacenamiento() {
        return cant_almacenamiento;
    }

    public void setCant_almacenamiento(int cant_almacenamiento) {
        this.cant_almacenamiento = cant_almacenamiento;
    }

    public consola getConsola() {
        return consola;
    }

    public void setConsola(consola consola) {
        this.consola = consola;
    } 
}
```

CLASE CONSOLA:

```
package u6_repaso_junio;

public class consola {
    private String nombre;
    private int num_mandos_originales, num_mandos_clon, gb_hdd_int, gb_hdd_ext;

    public consola(String nombre, int num_mandos_originales, int num_mandos_clon, int gb_hdd_int, int gb_hdd_ext) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.num_mandos_originales = num_mandos_originales;
        this.num_mandos_clon = num_mandos_clon;
        this.gb_hdd_int = gb_hdd_int;
        this.gb_hdd_ext = gb_hdd_ext;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getNum_mandos_originales() {
        return num_mandos_originales;
    }

    public void setNum_mandos_originales(int num_mandos_originales) {
        this.num_mandos_originales = num_mandos_originales;
    }

    public int getNum_mandos_clon() {
        return num_mandos_clon;
    }

    public void setNum_mandos_clon(int num_mandos_clon) {
        this.num_mandos_clon = num_mandos_clon;
    }

    public int getGb_hdd_int() {
        return gb_hdd_int;
    }

    public void setGb_hdd_int(int gb_hdd_int) {
        this.gb_hdd_int = gb_hdd_int;
    }

    public int getGb_hdd_ext() {
        return gb_hdd_ext;
    }

    public void setGb_hdd_ext(int gb_hdd_ext) {
        this.gb_hdd_ext = gb_hdd_ext;
    }
}
```

CLASE NEODATIS (consultas):

```
package u6_repaso_junio;

import org.neodatis.odb.ODB;
import org.neodatis.odb.ODBFactory;
import org.neodatis.odb.Objects;

public class neodatis {

    private final String ubicacion = "juegos.neodatis";

    public void nueva_consola(Object consola) {
        ODB odb = ODBFactory.open(ubicacion);
        odb.store(consola);
        odb.close();
    }

    public void nuevo_juego(Object juego) {
        ODB odb = ODBFactory.open(ubicacion);
        odb.store(juego);
        odb.close();
    }

    public void getConsolas(){
        ODB odb = ODBFactory.open(ubicacion);
        Objects<consola> obj = odb.getObjects(consola.class);
        System.out.println(obj.size()+ " consolas.");
        while (obj.hasNext()) {

            consola con = obj.next();
            System.out.println("Consola: " + con.getNombre()
                    + "\n Mandos originales :" + con.getNum_mandos_originales()
                    + "\n Mandos clon: " + con.getNum_mandos_clon()
                    + "\n Capacidad disco duro interno: "+con.getGb_hdd_int()
                    + "\n Capacidad disco duro externo: "+con.getGb_hdd_ext()+"\n");
        }

        odb.close();
    }

    public void getJuegos() {
        ODB odb = ODBFactory.open(ubicacion);
        Objects<juego> obj = odb.getObjects(juego.class);
        while (obj.hasNext()) {
            juego juego = obj.next();
            System.out.println("Título: "+juego.getTitulo()+
                    "\n Formato: "+juego.getFormato()+
                    "\n Cantidad de almacenamiento: "+ juego.getCant_almacenamiento()+" "+juego.getFormato()+
                    "\n Plataforma: "+juego.getConsola().getNombre()+"\n");
        }
        odb.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de Neodatis:

> To update an object, it must be previously loaded by ODB. By doing
>   this, ODB puts this object in a cache
>   (org.neodatis.odb.core.session.ICache) to be abble to detect new
>   objects from existing objects. So, to discover if it must execute an
>   update or an insert, ODB will check if object exist in cache, if it
>   does, it is an update, if it does not, it is an insert.

Lo que tienes que hacer es guardar la consola y luego recuperar el valor guardado y añadirle los juegos. Cuando lo guardas por separado, consolas y juegos el cree que son consolas distintas y al "no existir" la crea de nuevo puesto que no tendrá la clave primaria asignada al hacer el insert previamente. Además, asegúrate de que tienes ambas tablas relacionadas.

Comment: Después de escribir mi duda probé a hacer eso. Cargué la consola y luego la usé a la hora de crear el juego. Pero sigue pensando que es una nueva consola.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que al hacer la nueva inserción de tu juego, estás a su vez creando otro objeto consola.
Esto se debe a que ODB mantiene una referencia de todos los objetos insertados / actualizados MIENTRAS el objeto ODB se mantiene abierto.
Como realizas las inserciones abriendo / cerrando dicho objeto, Neodatis entiende que cada consola que le indicas es una nueva entrada.

Si quieres hacer inserciones de consola y usar esas mismas para tus juegos, tal y como lo tienes ahora, tienes que seguir estos pasos:

1. Elemento de lista
2. Insertar las consolas
3. Crear la clase de tu juego, y en la propiedad de consola en vez de referenciar al objeto que creaste previamente, hacer una llamada a la base de datos para traerte el que está ahí almacenado.
4. Hacer la inserción del juego.

La consulta puedes hacerla con una Criteria query. Te dejo el enlace donde lo explican:
http://neodatis.wikidot.com/criteria-queries

Si no, puedes mantener el objeto ODB abierto y cerrarlo al finalizar todas las inserciones. Pero recuerda, cada vez que lo cierres su "caché" se limpiará de nuevo

**EDITADO**
El método que empleo para hacer la consulta de consola es el siguiente:

```
 public consola getConsola(String consolaName) {
    ODB odb = ODBFactory.open(ubicacion);
    IQuery query = new CriteriaQuery(consola.class, Where.equal("nombre", consolaName));
    Objects p = odb.getObjects(query);
    consola con = null;
    while (p.hasNext())
    {
        con = (consola)p.next();
    }
    odb.close();

    return con;
}
```

Y lo llamo desde main como

```
juego resident_evil_6 = new juego("Resident Evil 6", "Bluray", 1, neo.getConsola("PS3"));
```

Si te vas al gestor de la base de datos podemos ver que los resultados son tres consolas, y cuatro juegos

[image: Resultado desde el gestor de Neodatis]

Comment: El caso es que cargar la consola e insertar un nuevo juego con esa consola cargada ya lo he hecho pero no cambia el resultado.
    public consola getConsola(String consola){
        ODB odb = ODBFactory.open(ubicacion);
        IQuery query = new CriteriaQuery(consola.class, Where.equal("nombre", consola));
        consola con = (consola)odb.getObjects(query).getFirst();
        odb.close();
        return con;
        
    }

Ya en el main:
        juego doom = new juego("DOOM", "Bluray", 1, neo.getConsola("PS4"));

Pero nada de nada.

Comment: Yo he usado este método para testearlo: ` public consola getConsola(String consolaName) {
     ODB odb = ODBFactory.open(ubicacion);
     IQuery query = new CriteriaQuery(consola.class, Where.equal("nombre", consolaName));
     Objects p = odb.getObjects(query);
     consola con = null;
     while (p.hasNext())
     {
      con = (consola)p.next();
     }
     odb.close();
     
     return con;
    }`

Comment: Es muy similar a mi función. Lo único que cambia es que yo espero/obligo a que solo devuelva un resultado del objeto consola, pues nunca ha de haber una consola repetida. Al crear el objeto juego yo también llamo a la función. ¿Será que netbeans me está vacilando?

Comment: Prueba a limpiar la base de datos (genera una nueva), y debuggea to aplicación para ver si está haciendo correctamente las llamadas. Ve paso a paso porque se me hace raro que no esté haciendo esa operación bien si es el código tal que así

Comment: La he borrado ya varias veces y creado otras tantas.